# How to padding in change bootstrap container class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Ive been trying to remove the 15px padding that the container class gives elements.

HTML:

```
<div class="container body-container" id="mainContent">
     some stuff
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container.body-container {
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

I've tried many things.  I've tried changing the container class itself and make a custom container class like this code.  In the image below Im looking at the code and the displayed padding in chrome.  It shows that there is 15px padding around the container element.  I want all the padding gone.

[image]

The entire css file, as requested:

```
 body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: #B47B10;
    font-size: 16px;
 }


#nameTitle{
    color: #003300;
    text-align: center;
}
#titleCaption{
    color: #B47B10;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
}

#topBar{
    background-color: #B47B10;
}

#navBarLink{
    color: #B47B10;
}
#navBarLink:hover{
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#myCarousel{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    max-width: 100%;
    position:relative;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
}

#cImage{
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
#wellItem{
    padding-top: 15px;
    background-color: #B47B10;
}
#wellItem:hover{
    background-color: #A46B00;
}

#invertedLink{
    color: #003300;
}
#invertedLink:hover{
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.body-container {
    padding: 0px!important;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.carousel-caption {
    padding: 0px;

    position: relative;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
}
.input-group{
    margin-right: 30px;
}
.multi-item-carousel{
  .carousel-inner{
    > .item{
        transition: 500ms ease left;
    }
    .active{
      &.left{
        left:-33%;
      }
      &.right{
        left:33%;
      }
    }
    .next{
      left: 33%;
    }
    .prev{
      left: -33%;
    }

    @media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
      > .item{
        // use your favourite prefixer here
        transition: 500ms ease all;
        backface-visibility: visible;
        transform: none!important;
      }
    }
  }

  .carouse-control{
    &.left, &.right{
      background-image: none;
    }
  }
}
.navbar-inverse {
  background-color: #003300;
  border-color: #080808;
}
@media(min-width:768px) {
    body {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your css is working just fine.
I think it's your position of importing the files

put bootstrap.min.css before your custom css file like this

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="css/my_style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

The css file which is at the bottom will override the others.
Hope this will help

It can also be the [cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_cache) problem as the website can be cached in your browser.
So clear the cache and then run your code or run your code in  incognito window

```css
.container.body-container{
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  
<div class="container body-container" id="mainContent">
  some stuff
 </div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't it either.  I already have my custom css file I'm using below the bootstrap.min.css.

Comment: Have you run my code snippet it work fine as you can see here

Comment: Ok now i am getting your problem you have another css which is overriding this one. Can you provide the full css file code

Comment: For my situation it must have to do with the rest of the html elements.  I'm not sure what going on exactly but kendrickkesley's answer works.

Comment: It's a workaround not a solution for the question. The question is why? its taking padding not how to suppress it.

Comment: here is the actual site if you care http://www.idahocampgroundreview.com/Kevin/samplepage.php

Comment: I also added the css file code, as requested, to the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132651/discussion-between-aman-rawat-and-khaines0625).

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
.body-container {
    padding: 0px!important;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

or

```
<div class="container" style="padding:0!important" id="mainContent">
     some stuff
</div>
```

Comment: the inline style worked! Thanks!  ..though this feel kinda improper.  As long as it works its all good it just makes me wonder what it was that was making it be so stubborn.

Comment: I think you can see it in the chrome's inspect element. Inspect the style of the element and find where's the padding-right: 15px and padding-left: 15px located.